# How to update context in dust helper for chunk.render

Tags: dust.js

I am using linkedin's version of dustjs. I want to create a custom helper that updates the context to be more specific for rendering the body of the context.

How can I do that?

Say the context is currently:

```
{
    title: "News",
    items: [],
    nav: {
       logo: 'logo.png',
       items: []
    },
    body: {
       items: []
    }
}
```

If I just use chunk.render(bodies.block,context) in my helper, it would be at context level. But I'd like it to render with a scope at the lower 'nav' level:

```
{
 logo: 'logo.png',
 items: []
}
```

Somewhat related, is it possible to set the scope/context of the chunk.render call to an object that is higher up?

Say I had been using the array looping helper {#items}{/items} and context inside the loop body is set to each array element, could I write a helper that sets the context for its own body to be higher up and in completely different branch of the object? Like 'body' one?

I know about using {#items:body}, but I am interested in changing scope to different parts of the object based on a key stored in each array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render using a selected subset of the context, you can use `context.rebase` to generate a new context.

This example uses a context helper for succinctness, but you could use a regular Dust helper as well.

### Template

```
{#subcontext key="nav"}
  {#items}{.}{/items}
{/subcontext}
```

### Context

```
{
  "subcontext": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    var subcontext = context.get(params.key);
    return chunk.render(bodies.block, context.rebase(subcontext));
  },
  "items": ["Oh", "No"],
  "nav": {
    "items": ["Yay", "Yay"]
  }
}
```

---

In response to your second question:

Yes, you can traverse backwards up the context stack. I'll leave this part as an exercise for you, but here's the guidance that you should need:

Your `context` object in your helper has a property called `stack`. `stack` has a property called `tail`, which is itself an instance of `Stack`. There's one nested `tail` for each level of your context, so depending on how you want to do the backwards lookup, you could move anywhere on the stack and then call `context.rebase` with `tail`'s `head` to set a different context.

Comment: Thank you, Interrobang! I understand, now!