# How to switch context in a dust.js helper

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I have a model that gets sent to dust in the form of:

```
{
    "name": "Build Name",
    "date": "03/09/2015",
    "modules": [
        {
            "name": "Cyber Strength",
            "module_group": "Standard",
            "module_type": "Training Modules"
        },
        {
            "name": "Phil",
            "module_group": "Games",
            "module_type": "Training Modules"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'd like to be able to make a dust helper function in the form of....

```
{@getModules module_group="Standard" module_type="Training Modules"}
    <li>{name}</li>
{/getModules}
```

I can't simply iterate through the modules doing `{#modules}{/modules}` becuase I want to only show modules that match my criteria (module_group and module_type).

Can anyone help me come up with a helper function that can switch to the correct context of modules where `{name}` will print the module name and not the build name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update context in dust helper for chunk.render](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868108/how-to-update-context-in-dust-helper-for-chunk-render)

Comment: I wrote a helper in the above question that should do what you want. You'll have to update the logic to "pluck" the correct object, but then just rebase your context onto that object.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can iterate over `modules`, because you can just filter out the ones you don't want.

To get access to the core Dust logic helpers, you'll want to include the [`dustjs-helpers`](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers) module as well.

Then, you can use the `{@eq}` helper to only work with the objects that meet your criteria.

```
{#modules}
  {@eq key=module_group value="Standard"}
  {@eq key=module_type value="Training Modules"}
    {name} is the right type!
  {/eq}
  {/eq}
{/modules}
```

However, I think that writing a helper as you suggested makes your template a lot clearer and easier to read! To get help writing a helper, check out the link I posted as a comment above, and read the [Dust documentation on writing context helpers](http://dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers/).